# Even larger fonts in Linux console

Tags: console, fonts

When I run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure console-setup` I can select a larger font to use for my console (to be clear, I mean the TTY prompts you get with Ctrl+Alt+F1-6), up to 16x32.

What if I want even larger? I'm on a high DPI screen so even 16x32 is a bit small. And how do I add more fonts to it (there seem to be only a handful of font choices)?

I am on Debian buster.

Comment: Please click [edit] and advise which version of which distro you are using. Please don't reply with [Add Comment} as old comments get pushed off the screen if more pile up; we want all the info needed to solve your question in that question.

Comment: I don't know if you want to go this route, but recompiling the kernel with options to make the resolution used for TTY lower. Of course, I realize not everyone wants to dive into manual kernel compiling, and I certainly would not recommend it if your only motivation is to make the screen font larger.

Comment: @JasonKLai Ah, at least it's **a** way. But no, I would rather not recompile the kernel - there's bound to be some special parameter I'll forget to include that breaks even more things. =)